# Merge multiple columns into one, dropping duplicates across a row and removing nan values

Tags: python, merge, col

I am trying to merge multiple columns into a single column while dropping duplicates and dropping null values but keeping the rows. What I have:

```
Index  |   A  |  B  | C
0      |  nan | nan | nan
1      |   1  |  1  | nan
2      |   x  |  2  | nan
```

What I need:

```
Index  |   New_col  
0      |   
1      |   1  
2      |   x,2
```

What I have tried:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.array([['nan', 'nan', 'nan'], ['nan', 1, 1], ['nan', 'x', 2]]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df['a]=df[['a','b','c]].agg(', '.join, axis=1)
```

Also tried: .stack().unstack()  and .join but I cannot get these to remove duplicates by row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if set preserves the order of incoming elements, but we can chain some operations together

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""A|B|C
||
1|1|
x|2|"""), sep="|", dtype="object")

>>> df.apply(lambda x: ",".join(set([str(i) for i in x if pd.notnull(i)])), axis=1)
0
1      1
2    x,2
dtype: object
```

Comment: This works like a charm for strings and for floats/int. Thanks for the code. (I upvoted your comment but since I dont hav 15 reputations it wont show up for a bit but thanks none the less)